# Trace of a matrix by eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $A$ denote matrix based on another matrix $B$:
\begin{align}
  A = (I + \lambda B)^{-1}
\end{align}
$I$ is the identity matrix and $\lambda$ is a coefficient.

Decomposing $B$ as $USU^T$ where $U^TU=I$:
\begin{align}
  A = (I + \lambda USU^T)^{-1} = U(I + \lambda S)^{-1}U^T \quad \text{(eq. 1)}
\end{align}
and the trace of $A$ is given as:
\begin{align}
  \operatorname{tr}(A) = \operatorname{tr}\left(U(I + \lambda S)^{-1}U^T\right) = \operatorname{tr}\left((I + \lambda S)^{-1}U^TU\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + \lambda s_{ii}}  
\end{align}
where $s_{ii}$ are the eigenvalues of $B$.

Given diagonal matrix $X$, we define a new matrix $C$:
\begin{align}
  C = (X + \lambda B)^{-1} X
\end{align}
Do the identities in eq. (1) hold when there is an arbitrary diagonal matrix in place of the identity matrix such that the trace of $C$ can be written simply as shown below?
\begin{align}
  \operatorname{tr}(C) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_{ii}}{x_{ii} + \lambda s_{ii}}
\end{align}

Comment: You're right - it's the trace that's equal. I've corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ commutes with $B$, and (possibly not necessarily) if $X$ or $B$ is invertible, then the claim is true for $\lambda$ such that $X+\lambda \,B$ is invertible, provided that the ordering of $\left(x_{i,i}\right)_{i=1,2,\ldots,n}$ and the ordering of $\left(s_{i,i}\right)_{i=1,2,\ldots,n}$ are ***compatible***.  If not, then the claim can fail.  Here is a counterexample.

Let $X:=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $B:=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.  Then, $x_{1,1}=1$, $x_{2,2}=2$, and $\big\{s_{1,1},s_{2,2}\big\}=\{-1,+1\}$.  Now, for $\lambda:=1$, we get
$$C=(X+\lambda\,B)^{-1}\,X=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\,\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&-2\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}\,.$$
Thus, $$\text{trace}(C)=4\neq \sum\limits_{i=1}^2\,\frac{x_{i,i}}{x_{i,i}+\lambda\,s_{i,i}}\,,$$
as the only way the right-hand side is defined is when $s_{1,1}=+1$ and $s_{2,2}=-1$, which makes
$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^2\,\frac{x_{i,i}}{x_{i,i}+\lambda\,s_{i,i}}=\frac{1}{1+1}+\frac{2}{2-1}=\frac{5}{2}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for the example. Is it conceivable that there is an expression as simple as $\sum_i (1/1+\lambda s_i)$ when the matrix is not the identity matrix?

Comment: Not that I know of, and I don't expect that there is anything simple.  Inverting a matrix often result in something very nasty.