# A common, ambiguous matrix operation (flanking matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, arithmetic, matrix-equations

There is a certain matrix operation that I've seen performed in several proofs/derivations, but I've never been able to find a clear rule for it. I'm not even sure how to search for it online. It looks like this:

**A** + **B****C****D**
= **B**(**A** + **C**)**D**

For a working example, see (eq. 1) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869975/trace-of-a-matrix-by-eigendecomposition).

Under what conditions is this true? Do **A**, **B**, and/or **D** have to meet some criteria? Is there a rule for this that I've missed somewhere? It seems like there would be, given the number of times I've encountered it.

Comment: Wrong, there is no such “rule”. In fact, (eq. 1) follows from the basic identity $UB^{-1}U^{-1} = (UBU^{-1}) ^{-1}$.

Comment: I still don't understand how the identity matrix (or the **A** in my example above) gets inside the parenthesis. The basic identity you provided has no term being added to it.

Comment: If $B=I+A$, then $UBU^{-1} = UIU^{-1} + UAU^{-1} = I+ UAU^{-1} $.

Comment: That makes a little more sense, thanks. Is it fair to say then that the above "rule" is always true if **A** is a scalar matrix and $B = {D}^{-1}$ ?